# An application that tests different versions of a project

Tags: python

I have been given a task to create a GUI or maybe a web app that will let the developers on a project test different versions of the code that's being developed:

1. Store the compiled executables and their associated config files of all baseline in a   directory on the server.
2. The program that tests the executables can be located in the same directory on the server. Whatever works.
3. Let the user decide upon two executables, which displays their contents, and let the user change the parameters if he wishes.
4. The user should now be able to hit a button which runs both executables with their associated parameters.
5. The executable create text files containing a list of numbers representing a path in space. These should be graphicaly displayed so that the user can compare the two versions of the executables and the parameters they were fed.

I have a little experience with Perl and some C++ experience, but I was hoping this could be an excuse to take up Python, but I have a few questions:

I was just wondering if there are better languages/tools suited for the job?

What libraries should I use?

What should I use if we decide this should be done through a browser?

Any other things a relatively unexperienced programmer should know before embarking on something like this?

Many thanks!

Comment: I would look at buildbot for this .... http://trac.buildbot.net/